# How do I show a message box on my calculator when dividing by 0 in C#?

Tags: c#, forms

I'm trying to make a calculator for school using c# forms. I have encountered a problem when dividing with 0. I need to make it when I divide with zero after pressing the '/' button it should pop up a message box with an error.

So far I've tried different ways to do this. The one shown below is the closest I got to the actual answer. The only problem I have now, is that when I do 8 / 0 it works and shows the message box. But if I  try to do 0 / 8, it also shows the message box when it shouldn't. I would really like some help with this.
Here's my code for my equal button:

```
private void btnEqual_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtOutput.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Operation is not allowed.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else
            {
                if (Int32.TryParse(txtOutput.Text, out int Number))
                {
                    History.Add(stevilo);
                    lstBox.Items.Insert(0, Number);
                    lstBox.Items.Insert(0, "equal");
                    txtOutput.Clear();
                }
            }
            double Answer = 0;
        string Operation = "plus";

        foreach (var CheckHistory in History)
        {
            if (CheckHistory is int)
            {
                if (Operation == "plus")
                    Answer += (int) CheckHistory;
                if(Operation == "minus") 
                    Answer -= (int) CheckHistory;
                if (Operation == "multiply")
                    Answer *= (int) CheckHistory;
                else if (Operation == "divide")
                {
                    if (lstBox.Items.Contains(0) == true )
                    {
                        txtOutput.Text = lstBox.Items[lstBox.Items.Count - 1].ToString();
                        MessageBox.Show("Dividing with 0 is impossible.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

                        txtOutput.Clear();
                        lstBox.Items.Clear();
                        txtAnswer.Clear();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Answer /= (int)CheckHistory;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
                Operation = (string)CheckHistory;
```

Here's my code for my '/' button:

```
private void btnDivide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtOutput.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Operation not allowed.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        else
        {
            if (Int32.TryParse(txtOutput.Text, out int Number))
            {
                History.Add(Number);
                lstBox.Items.Insert(0, Number);
                lstBox.Items.Insert(0, "divide");
                txtOutput.Clear();
                History.Add("divide");
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is an image of how my calculator looks so it's easier to imagine how it functions [image]

It's all happening in my equals button. I'm guessing I have to change something in the if() statement.

```
if (lstBox.Items.Contains(0) == true )
                    {
                        txtOutput.Text = lstBox.Items[lstBox.Items.Count - 1].ToString();
                        MessageBox.Show("Dividing with 0 is impossible.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

                        txtOutput.Clear();
                        lstBox.Items.Clear();
                        txtAnswer.Clear();
                    }
```

Cause now it's just checking if I pressed 0 before in the whole list.

Edit: I apologize for using images for code. First time posting to Stackoverflow. Didn't realise I just had to click ctrl+K to make it a code snippet..

Edit 2: Added more code snippets and an image of calculator UI.

Comment: please post the actual code instead of just pictures.

Comment: Yeah , didn't realise I could, since it only gave me options for HTML, CSS and java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just wrap everything in a `try-catch-block` and show the error message when catching a `DivideByZeroException`, e.g.:

```cs
var num1 = 8;
var num2 = 0;

try
{
   var result = num1 / num2;
}
catch(DivideByZeroException e)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Cannot divide by zero");
}
```

**Update with actual code from question**

```cs
foreach (var CheckHistory in History)
{
    if (CheckHistory is int)
    {
        if (Operation == "plus")
            Answer += (int) CheckHistory;
        if(Operation == "minus") 
            Answer -= (int) CheckHistory;
        if (Operation == "multiply")
            Answer *= (int) CheckHistory;
        else if (Operation == "divide")
        {
            try
            {
                Answer /= (int)CheckHistory;
            }
            catch(DivideByZeroException)
            {
                txtOutput.Text = lstBox.Items[lstBox.Items.Count - 1].ToString();
                MessageBox.Show("Dividing with 0 is impossible.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                txtOutput.Clear();
                lstBox.Items.Clear();
                txtAnswer.Clear();

                //If you need to stop the loop, you can optionally call 'break':
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But how would I implement this in my code, since I have more than just two variables. My calculator uses a text box to list box and then to list/array system.

Comment: You can put the `try-catch` around your entire calculation routine. For a more detailed answer, I would need to see more code and a more concise description of what you're trying to do highlighting the exact problem.

Comment: I tried the try-catch exactly as you updated it, but the 'e' is already used in the button click function and it causes a bunch of problems to arise. If the 'e' is not needed then the try-catch does not work.

Comment: "e" is just a variable name for the exception, it can be named anything else or skipped entirely if you're not accessing it. But you'll need the `catch(DivideByZeroException)` part. You might also want to stop the calculation loop. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, for some reason this isn't working for me..

Comment: I'm just working with what you're offering me as information. What isn't working exactly, what are you seeing? Are you may be leaving out potentially important details?

Comment: When I start the program and I try to divide 8/0 nothing shows up, it just goes through and gives me the number I pressed. So if I clicked 8/0 it just shows me 8. If I try to do 0/8 it also just gives me an answer of 8.

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint in the catch-clause to see if it's actually catching the exception while debugging?

Comment: Yes I used the breakpoint, it does exactly what I described in the comment above. Is there any way I could use an if statement to do the division with 0?

Comment: So it doesn't catch the exception at all?

Comment: Nope, it's almost like it completely skips it. But I did find a way to do it. I created a new variable which checks for the previous insert to the list box before the divide button was clicked. And if the previous insert is 0, then it pops up the message box.